# Converting IMAP to POP3

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pop3, hotmail

I would like to set my settings on Microsoft Windows Hotmail to allow me to change from IMAP to POP3. I'm trying to change a setting where all my university emails have been downloaded to my Outlook and then delete those emails on the server itself – without interrupting or touching the emails on my Outlook inbox.

I am not sure what else to do. I have contacted Microsoft for help, they said to me to contact my university, but they can't help.

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new outlook profile
- Enter the server, username and password for the POP3 account at hotmail there
- If you are really sure, that this is what you want, then configure it, to not *leave mails on POP3 server*.
- Done.